# How do I get the type of a value in Scheme?

Tags: dynamic, types, scheme

I want a function that gets the type of a value at runtime.  Example use:

```
(get-type a)
```

where `a` has been `define`d to be some arbitrary Scheme value.

How do I do this?  Or do I have to implement this myself, using a cond stack of `boolean?`, `number?` etc. ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Scheme implementations with a Tiny-CLOS-like object system, you can just use `class-of`. Here's a sample session in Racket, using Swindle:

```
$ racket -I swindle
Welcome to Racket v5.2.1.
-> (class-of 42)
#<primitive-class:exact-integer>
-> (class-of #t)
#<primitive-class:boolean>
-> (class-of 'foo)
#<primitive-class:symbol>
-> (class-of "bar")
#<primitive-class:immutable-string>
```

And similarly with Guile using GOOPS:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> ,use (oop goops)
scheme@(guile-user)> (class-of 42)
$1 = #<<class> <integer> 14d6a50>
scheme@(guile-user)> (class-of #t)
$2 = #<<class> <boolean> 14c0000>
scheme@(guile-user)> (class-of 'foo)
$3 = #<<class> <symbol> 14d3a50>
scheme@(guile-user)> (class-of "bar")
$4 = #<<class> <string> 14d3b40>
```

Answer (score 13):

In Racket, you can use the [`describe`](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=describe.plt&owner=williams) package by Doug Williams from PLaneT.  It works like this:

```
> (require (planet williams/describe/describe))
> (variant (λ (x) x))
'procedure
> (describe #\a)
#\a is the character whose code-point number is 97(#x61) and
general category is ’ll (letter, lowercase)
```

Comment: This package is indeed helpful. I wish it was part of the core Racket.

Answer (score 9):

All of the answers here are helpful, but I think that people have neglected to explain why this might be hard; the Scheme standard doesn't include a static type system, so values can't be said to have just one "type". Things get interesting in and around subtypes (e.g. number vs floating-point-number) and union types (what type do you give to a function that returns either a number or a string?).

If you describe your desired use a bit more, you might discover that there are more specific answers that will help you more.

Comment: He says "at runtime", so this has nothing to do with static types. It's the dynamic (runtime) types of values he's after

Comment: You're missing John's point, in the sense that the dynamic runtime types don't always have enough information to disambiguate.  Concrete example: let's say that I have a program that deals with colors and names.  I may choose to represent values of these types with just strings.  Then if I see the word "Gray", I don't have enough information to distinguish the type because I'm using the same representation.

Comment: Ditto; you can delete the word "static" from my post, and it still makes sense. Danny's example is a good one. In fact, the C language has the same issue: there's no "what's the type of this value" operator, because many values have the same representation.

Comment: I don't see why the two examples you give poses any problem.  For the number vs floating-point-number case, return the latter since it is the least.  For the procedure case, just return `′procedure`.

Comment: Narrowly: what about the type "numbers-greater-than-zero" and "floating-point-numbers"? Neither of these fits inside the other one. More generally: you have a particular notion of types in mind, and you could certainly write a get-type that does what you want it to. You should do that!

Answer (score 5):

To check the type of something just add a question mark after the type, for example to check if x is a number:

```
(define get-Type
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((number? x) "Number")
          ((pair? x) "Pair")
          ((string? x) "String")
          ((list? x) "List"))))
```

Just continue with that.

Comment: The OP specifically asked if there were an alternative to this approach. Also, why use nested `if`s when you can use `cond`? \*boggles\*

Comment: @ewein @Chris Jester-Young is this missing any? For `(get-Type (car (string->list (number->string 5))))` this doesn't return anything.

Comment: Turns out for my case the missing bit was `character?`. For completeness sake there is also `vector?`.