# How to test whether two struct instances are of the same structure type in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

For example, I have two structure instances `s1` and `s2`, but I don't know the exact type of `s1` and `s2`. Is it possible to check whether `s1` and `s2` are of the same structure type or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not in general possible to check that property, namely because structs in Racket are often *opaque*, meaning that reflective operations give you limited or no information about the struct instance.

If the structure types are declared as *transparent*, however, it is possible to determine if they originated from the same structure type using `struct-info`.

```
#lang racket

(struct s () #:transparent)
(struct t () #:transparent)

(define-values (s-info _) (struct-info (s)))
(define-values (t-info _) (struct-info (t)))

(equal? s-info t-info)   ; => #f

(define-values (s-info-2 _) (struct-info (s)))

(equal? s-info s-info-2) ; => #t
```

If you just want an approximation of this information, you can follow Greg's advice and use `object-name`. Note that it is possible for two structure types that do not produce equivalent instances to have the same object name:

```
(define s1 (let () (struct s ()) (s)))
(define s2 (let () (struct s ()) (s)))
(equal? (object-name s1) (object-name s2)) ; => #t
```

Comment: To Asumu's excellent answer, I'd like to add: this kind of reflection feature often comes back to bite language designers; having a "class-of" makes it impossible to perform certain kinds of optimizations. It's hard to know without seeing your problem, but you might well be interested in the predicates (e.g. "point?" for a point structure) that are automatically defined for you.

Answer (score 4):

Racket -- `#lang racket`, the main/full language -- does *not* have a `type-of` or `class-of`.

Instead you could use [`object-name`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/inspectors.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._object-name%29%29) for this:

```
#lang racket

(struct s ())
(struct t ())

(define x (s))
(define y (s))
(define z (t))

(object-name x) ; 's
(object-name y) ; 's
(object-name z) ; 't
(equal? (object-name x) (object-name y)) ; #t
(equal? (object-name x) (object-name z)) ; #f
```

Comment: don't forget about the automatically-generated predicates, "s?" and "t?".

Comment: @JohnClements Definitely that's preferable when possible. But I thought Ben asked about the case where he doesn't know the exact types.

Answer (score 0):

(the original question was not restricted to racket)

Use [`type-of`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_tp_of.htm):

```
(eq (type-of s1) (type-of s2))
```

You can also use [`class-of`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_clas_1.htm) instead; it does not matter for structures but does matter for other types; you need to think carefully about what you are trying to do. `type-of` is more granular, but may not return an [`atom`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_atom.htm), so you might not be able to use [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) with it.

EDIT: it appears that [racket has `class-of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566886/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-a-value-in-scheme) too, so you can use that.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to make it clear that that I was asking a Racket specific question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ben: racket has class-of too

Comment: @sds I'm pretty sure Racket does not have a `type-of` or `class-of` function. Both [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=type-of) and [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=class-of) say "No matches found".

Comment: @GregHendershott: sds was talking about Chris' answer in the link he (sds) gives, which is actually about `swindle`'s [`class-of`](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/300/html/swindle/tiny-clos-doc.html) (`swindle` is an extension of `racket`, for anyone reading this).

Comment: @Metaxal I know about Swindle, which is a very cool CLOS-ish system. But although Swindle code is currently distributed with Racket, Swindle (a) has no doc included with Racket, (b) isn't Racket's `class` system, and (c) I don't believe `class-of` even works with arbitrary `struct`s. So although I realize it may seem like I'm being picky, I'm thinking of Ben trying to use `class-of` in the way he asked, and becoming very confused.

Comment: @GregHendershott: I was pretty sure you knew, I was just clarifying  which `class-of` we were talking about for anyone else reading this (your answer clarifies this further). I was replying to your comment, not to you in fact :)